# How to add custom folder to install project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

I am trying to deploy a piece of software.  It has become apparent that for backward compatibility I need to add a 'c:/abc/system' folder and populate it with some images, how do you do that?  c:/abc is not the installation directory but is a data store for the app when running.

Visual Studio 2008 gives you the option of adding a custom folder but we can't seem to find a way to define a custom path, that is not the installation path, in to which to put the folder and the images, so how do  you do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use [WindowsVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property:

- go to your setup project File System Editor
- right-click *File System on Target Machine* tree item and select **Add Special Folder -> Custom Folder** menu item
- select this custom folder and go to its Properties pane
- set **DefaultLocation** attribute to:

`[WindowsVolume]abc\system`

During install WindowsVolume will be resolved to your Windows partition, usually C:.